# react-native size doesn't shrink

Tags: android, react-native

Trying to make a smaller APK, currently the size is 21 MB. Hoping to reduce it to 10MB.

I do this inside `android/app/build.gradle`, but it doesn't reduce, I just want ARM support for now:

```
splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I hope this will helps you.

Open up android/app/build.gradle

Set def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true this would enable Progaurd to compress the Java Bytecode. This reduces the app size by a tad bit

Set def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true . Android devices support two major device artitectures armebi and x86. By default RN builds the native librariers for both these artitectures into the same apk.

more information to https://medium.com/@aswinmohanme/how-i-reduced-the-size-of-my-react-native-app-by-86-27be72bba640